# One .bat calls another and I get a command windows briefly flash on the screen

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 .bat files test1.bat and test2.bat and I get a window opening flash for a brief period that I do not want to happen.

test 1.bat is called by double clicking on an associated  file extension .zgb

test1.bat =

```
@echo off
START /MIN c:\test\test2.bat %1
exit
```

test2.bat =

```
@echo off
"c:\test\test.accdb" /cmd %1
exit
```

Why I use 2 .bat files is that if I call test2.bat directly I get a command window open the entire time until the Access program closes.

But the problem is that I still get a (less than a second) flash before the Access program is run.  I assume the flash is a command window being opened than minimized.

Is there any way to not have any visual indication of anything before the Access program opens?

Comment: `start "" /WAIT ...`

Comment: Your `test1.bat` does not __call__ the other batch file. It __starts__ a new command process for processing the lines in second batch file. There is the command __CALL__ to really __call__ another batch file from within a batch file while command __START__ is for running another batch file (script) or executable in a separate process. Run in a command prompt window `start /?` for help on this command. There is the option `/B` to run the script/executable as background process.

Comment: I think, it is not possible to prevent opening a console window on execution of `test1.bat`. You would need a Windows GUI executable (not a command line script) not opening a GUI window which runs `"c:\test\test.accdb" /cmd %1` as background process.